# Do all apps submitted to the Google Play store through one developer account need to be signed with the same key?

Tags: android, google-play, signing

I'm sumbitting an android app to Google Play and am following the process to sign my app.  However the documentation on the android development site seems unclear about whether or not every app I submit through my Google Play developer account should be signed with the same key or not.

From the [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

> Android requires that all apps be digitally signed with a certificate before they can be installed. Android uses this certificate to identify the author of an app, and the certificate does not need to be signed by a certificate authority. Android apps often use self-signed certificates. The app developer holds the certificate's private key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No the same app next version or its update should be signed with the same key. And if you want to upload new(different) app you have to generate new key and that key works for that app only and its updates. 
Like i have uploaded two apps on the playstore proQuiz gilpix and wallpaper.
The keys for both are different and if i want to upload next version of any app, I have to use their respective keys.
The keys are ment to identify the original owner of the android application and allow them to update the older app on the playstore.
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Does it *have* to be different? or that it *can* be different?

Comment: @AnandCU: It _can_ be different, and it's good practice if they are. Signing keys for an App can not be changed, so if you use the same for all your apps and later wants to transfer ownership a given app you'd have to disclose _the_ key that signs them all.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can use different signing certs for different applications.

Please read "Signing Your Applications" here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

> **Warning:** Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you
>   publish an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you
>   signed your app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your
>   app, since you must always sign all versions of your app with the same
>   key.

The important thing to note is that you:

> **"must always sign all versions of your app with the same key."**